# How to apply different templates with in same for loop by using lookup files

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I have the xml as below. Here I have two different templates with names 'Form1Template' and 'Form2template' with different logic inside. I need to apply 'Form1Template' for the forms with formcode of - HO650 and HO932, I need to apply 'Form2Template' for the forms with formcode of -HO700 and HO1000.  Below is the xsl by using which I can achieve this. But I don't want to hard code the 'formcode' in the If condition check, In real-time, I have 15 form codes It will be a mess if I hard code all in the ' IF' condition. I am thinking of having a lookup file for each category of forms as below, Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this by using lookup files (by checking the formcode category using lookup files)? or suggest to me if any better way to achieve this.

XML

```
<forms>
<formcode>HO650</formcode>
<formnbr>2</formnbr>

</forms>
<forms>
<formcode>HO700</formcode>
<formnbr>32</formnbr>

</forms>
<forms>
<formcode>HO932</formcode>
<formnbr>2</formnbr>

</forms>
<forms>
<formcode>HO1000</formcode>
<formnbr>2</formnbr>

</forms>
```

Form1template

```
<xsl:template name="Form1template">

 --some logic inside--
</xsl:template>
```

Form2template

```
<xsl:template name="Form2template">

 --some logic inside--
</xsl:template>
```

xslt code to invoke different templates for different form category

```
<xsl:for-each select="forms">

<xsl:if test="formcode='HO650' or formcode='HO932' ">
<xsl:call-template name="Form1template"/>

</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="formcode='HO700' or formcode='HO1000' ">
<xsl:call-template name="Form2template"/>

</xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each>
```

Sample lookup (Form1Categorylookup.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Properties>
<Property name="HO650">HO650</Property>
<Property name="HO932">HO932</Property>
</Properties>
```

Comment: What exactly can one lookup from your lookup sample?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you implement the standard approach of:

```
 <xsl:template match="/your-root-element">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="forms"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="forms[formcode='HO650' or formcode='HO932']">
    <!-- some logic inside -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="forms[formcode='HO700' or formcode='HO1000']">
    <!-- some other logic inside -->
</xsl:template>
```

Doing a lookup would be awkward in XSLT 1.0 because a match pattern cannot reference a variable.

---

If your processor supports it, you could use an extension function to shorten the match pattern to:

```
<xsl:template match="forms[formcode=str:tokenize('HO650,HO932', ',')]">
```